# Remove item from multidimensional array php

Tags: php

Here is the array:

```
 [cart] => Array
        (
            [ProductId] => Array
                (
                    [0] => P121100001
                    [1] => P121100002
                )

            [SellerId] => Array
                (
                    [0] => S12110001
                    [1] => S12110001
                )

            [SpecifyId] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 2
                )

            [Quantity] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 1
                )

            [Price] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 12
                    [1] => 29
                )

            [TotalPrice] => 41
        )
```

I have the ProductId and I want to remove all the other items matching P121100002's key.

Is there an easy way to do this I can't can seem to come up with one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can loop through the full array and use `unset()` to, well, "unset" the specified index:

```
$index = array_search($cart['ProductId'], 'P121100002');
if ($index !== false) {
    foreach ($cart as $key => $arr) {
        unset($cart[$key][$index]);
    }
}
```

The slight caveat to this approach is that it may disrupt your index orders. For instance, say you have:

```
[ProductId] => Array (
    [0] => P121100001
    [1] => P121100002
    [2] => P121100003
)
```

And you want to remove `P121100002`, which has a corresponding index of `1`. Using `unset($cart['ProductId'][1])` will cause your array's to become:

```
[ProductId] => Array (
    [0] => P121100001
    [2] => P121100003
)
```

This may be something to remain concerned with if you're going to use a `for` loop to iterate through in the future. If it is, you can use `array_values()` to "reset" the indexes in the `unset()` loop from above:

```
foreach ($cart as $key => $arr) {
    unset($cart[$key][$index]);
    $cart[$key] = array_values($cart[$key]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach($yourArray['ProductId'] as $key => $value) {
    if ($value == $productIdToRemove) {
        foreach($yourArray as $deleteKey => $deleteValue) {
            unset($yourArray[$deleteKey][$key]);
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use array_key_exists along with the unset() function